# How to fetch call log details from an android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anyone please tell me how to fetch call log details from android emulator?
where does this type of data reside on phone?
waiting for answers. :)
thanks.

Comment: It does not mean that I havn't tried..but were looking for the best method..anyone might have come across..!

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
adb shell

#cd /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases

# sqlite3 contacts2.db

SQLite version 3.5.0

Enter ".help" for instructions

sqlite> select * from calls;
```

You can fetch all call log details from android emulator .

Answer (score 0):

The call log data is co-located in the contacts db.
Here's the blog post where the following code snippet came from:
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/phonecalls.html

```
adb shell
#cd /data/data/com.google.android.providers.contacts/databases
# sqlite3 contacts.db
SQLite version 3.5.0
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .dump
```

As you can see, the post is from 2008, so things might have changed since then. Your best bet is to peruse the developer reference on [developer android com]

Answer (score 0):

got the answer..its using content provider only.
foll the link:
http://www.anddev.org/images/tut/basic/calllog_displayer/screencast.htm

Comment: this sounds a good alternative to reading the sqlite db directly, but on my phone it throws `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider`